client/server problems with hostname and port on raspberry pi web interface
I'm using docker compose and two docker images for a web based environment-setting program. I have one server which saves the environment variable to a file, and I have a client that interacts with the user and passes the user's input on to the server. When I start the two up, on my desktop, the two work as expected. Then I move them to a raspberry pi. When I do this the client works, but I have trouble passing anything to the server. I want to run the client from google-chrome that is on my desktop. The client runs on port 5173 on the pi. The server listens at port 8008 on the pi.
To access the client I type this at my google-chrome address bar: raspberrypi.local:5173
The client never finds the server. I've tried identifying the server with this address on the pi: localhost:8008
I've also tried identifying the server with this address on the pi: 127.0.0.1:8008
What can I do to make this work?? Thanks.
Edit: I will try to post my docker compose file below. Unfortunately it still doesn't work on my raspberry pi.
services:
client:
    build: client/.
    ports:
        - "5173:5173"
    network_mode: host 
server:
    build: express/.
    ports:
        - "8008:8008"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
        - /home:/home

volumes:
home:

You haven't posted you compose, so I'm guessing you don't have host network mode enabled
services:
  my_service:
    image: my_image
    network_mode: host
    ...

doing it will use the network stack of the host and you will be able to reach the server.
